# Excessive delay in events retrieval using WSO Siddhi Java Library

Tags: java, siddhi

I am using the Java Library of Siddhi [1] , and have noticed that there is a considerable delay to retrieve and process events which are generated by the Siddhi runtime. Although two Siddhi events may have Siddhi event timestamps with a time difference of X seconds, the relevant application-level timestamps which are generated upon reception of Siddhi events are generated in the same second. To illustrate (all timestamps are trimmed to seconds):

- Siddhi event 1 timestamp : `1571059612`
- Siddhi event 2 timestamp : `1571059616`
- Application timestamp upon Siddhi event 1 reception: `1571059617`
- Application timestamp upon Siddhi event 2 reception: `1571059617`

The application timestamps are correct - i.e the Siddhi event propagation is delayed. Also, the Siddhi event timestamps have been verified by setting application timestamps to be equal to the Siddhi event timestamps. However, as the Siddhi events are created over a time window, I cannot consider the option of using the real - but delayed - Siddhi timestamps. This behaviour is unexpected, as events are expected to be received when they are generated.

The application excerpt in question is abstracted by the following code sample:

```java
running_siddhi_thread.getSiddhi_app_runtime().addCallback(output_stream_name, new StreamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void receive(Event[] events) {
        for (Event event : events) {
                //retrieval and processing of event
                do_processing_based_on_event(event) //this includes the Application timestamp generation
                create_new_message_with_timestamp(params)
            }
        }
});
```

The Siddhi query triggered is of the form:

```
from inputstream #window.timeBatch(5 sec )
select avg(attr1) as avg_attr1, avg(attr2) as avg_attr2
having avg_attr1>1000 and avg_attr2>800
insert into output_stream_name;
```

I verified that in Siddhi events are shown in the logs in the exact second that they happen, i.e at timestamps `1571059612` and `1571059616`. The event with a timestamp of `1571059612` means that `attr1` and `attr2` values were examined since `1571059607`, and that their averages were found to surpass the limits at `1571059612`.  The problem is that in the case of the Java library the events are published with a delay.

Is there a special option which needs to be set (e.g at thread level) to ensure that events from Siddhi are propagated with a shorter delay?

[1] https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/siddhi-as-a-java-library/

Comment: What window are you using for this?

Comment: I am using a 5 second window in Siddhi

Answer (score 0):

Siddhi keeps the timestamp of the original event during the pipeline. The timestamp you are getting will be from the time event is sent into the siddhi pipeline

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post an answer. Yes, I agree with this but what is unexpected is that I retrieve the detected event with a delay of up to 5 seconds

Comment: Are you using `insert into` or `insert all events into` in the query?

Comment: I am using the `insert into` statement

Comment: This is not a delay. The application timestamp is the retrieved time, I agree. However, the timestamp in the siddhi event is not updated in case of a window. Let's say I have a time batch window of 5 seconds, I send an event at 50th second. The event received at 55th second will still have the timestamp of 50th second. Since that is when I sent in the event

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please see the updated question